# mysql UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE from servlet does not execute but returns no errors!

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, windows-7, data-manipulation

I have been on this for three days and cannot find a solution.

I have a Android app -> Java Servlet -> Tomcat 7 container -> mySql 5.5 db architecture. 
OS: Windows 7

When I executeUpdate(statement) eg. INSERT, it returns the int rows affected by query, mysql log shows the receieved query but the database remains empty. I can insert the query manually and it works, then using a select statement I have no prob retrieving the contents of the db. I don't get any exceptions/errors on either side and I just can't get my head around it. Checked permissions etc. multiple times.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: do you commit the transaction ?

Comment: WOW sometimes it just helps writing it out! Thank you so much! I had it running on Mac previously and autocommit = true.